# Python classes: Inheritance vs Instantiation

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm creating a GUIclass that uses Frame() as its base class.

In my GUIclass’s init method I want to create a Frame widget

Right now I have:

```
class GUIclass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        frame = Frame(self, parent)
```

But I've seen this elsewhere for the third line:

```
Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

I'm new to programming, python and definitely inheritance and I wanted to know if I understand the difference between the two correctly. I did a lot of researching and reading, I promise, but I couldn't quite find anything that made it completely clear:

In the first situation I don't call the init method as I created a Frame object (frame) and when an object is created its init method is called implicitly by python.

In the second scenario, one is calling the init method on the class (which I believe is totally legit?) because a Frame object wasn't created, so therefore wouldn't do it automatically.

Is that right?

I've also seen:

```
frame = Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

which really threw me off. Is this just someone doing something redundant or is there a reason for this?

Thank you for your help, I want to take it slow for now and make sure I fully understand any and every line of code I write as I go rather than writing and running a whole program I half understand.

Comment: You should use the second one: `Frame.__init__(self, parent)`

Comment: The first is simply incorrect as it creates an unnecessary frame in the initializer of a frame-based object.

Comment: The second and third are super calls to the parent initializer in frame, such that the initializer of the child class will extends the basics, not override the basics. But there is no need to assign the result of a super call making the third incorrect.

Comment: The best solution would be to use `super().__init__(*arguments)`(assuming python3) in python2 this would be `super(GUIclass, self).__init__(*arguments)` (assuming new-style classes). Furthermore PEP8 mandates to call the class `GUIClass`.

Comment: Unfortunately super calls aren't supported in Tkinter,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should call

```
super(GUIclass, self).__init__(parent)
```

This is the proper way to call (all) your inherited `__init__()` method(s).  It has in many cases identical results compared to the mentioned

```
Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

which only lacks the abstraction concerning the inheritance relationships and states the class `Frame` as the one and only class whose `__init__()` method you might want to call (more about that later).

The also mentioned

```
frame = Frame(self.parent)
```

is wrong in this context.  It belongs to another pattern of object relationship, namely *contents* relationship instead of *inheritance* relationship (which you aim at).  It will *create* a new object of class `Frame` instead of initializing the `Frame` parts of yourself; in inheritance relationships you *are* a `Frame`, so you have to initialize `yourself` as one as well as initializing your specialized parts (which is done in the rest of your `__init__()` method).  In *contents* relationship models you merely *have* a `Frame`.

Now, what about that "slight" difference I mentioned above between calling `super(GUIclass, self).__init__(parent)` and `Frame.__init__(self, parent)`?

To understand that you need to dig deeper into inheritance relationships and the various possibilities these offer, especially with multiple inheritance.

Consider a diamond-shaped relationship model which looks like this:

```
          Frame
          /   \
    GUIclass  SomeOtherClass
          \   /
       AnotherClass
```

In your current scenario you only have the top left two classes, but one never knows what's going to come, and you should always code in a way so that the next user of your code keeps all options.

In this diamond-shaped pattern you have `AnotherClass` which inherits `GUIClass` and `SomeOtherClass` which in turn both inherit `Frame`.

If you now use the pattern `Frame.__init__(self, parent)` in both `GUIclass` and `SomeOtherClass`, then calling their `__init__()` methods from the `__init__()` method of `AnotherClass` will result in a doubled calling of the `Frame`'s `__init__()` method.  This typically is not intended, and to take care that this does not happen, the `super` call was invented.  It takes care that a decent calling order calls each of the `__init__()` methods only and exactly once.

Comment: The `super` arguments go in the other order.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.  (I never recall those correctly, so if you pranked me, I just disimproved that ;-)

Comment: Ahh it all makes sense now, I think I see the difference. 
So would I be correct in saying the first one does technically initialize a frame but it creates a separate frame object rather than saying this object has these frame properties and then some - the then some being whatever else is in my child classes __init__?

Comment: I also see the use in making code that won't fall apart when someone else comes along, right now I'm doing it alone but I do hope to be a programmer some day so that is great advice that I hadn't thought about yet. Best get in the practice now! I'd plus ten for that if I could

Comment: One more thing, at the moment I'm using Tkinter for this project, am I right to say super calls aren't supported using Tkinter? Is there another way in Tkinter or do I just stick with __init__ for that?

Comment: Yes, the first one *creates* a separate object and does not initialize the frame aspect of `self`.  Whether Tkinter supports `super`:  Any class which inherits `object` supports the `super` mechanism.  I'm not sure which Tkinter class is your Frame, but you can have a look at `Frame.__bases__` to see if `<type 'object'>` is inherited by it.  If it is not, don't use the `super` mechanism but stick to the `Frame.__init__(self, parent)` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `Frame.__init__(self, parent)` as Tkinter doesn't support super calls